# How to change bounce py function

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I wanted to replicate a potential that allows me to change the movement of the balls in this code

i

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure(1)
plt.clf()
plt.axis([-10, 10, -10, 10])

# Define properties of the "bouncing balls"
n = 50 #cantidad pelotas
pos = (20 * np.random.sample(n*2) - 10).reshape(n, 2)
vel = (0.3 * np.random.normal(size=n*2)).reshape(n, 2)
sizes = 100 * np.random.sample(n) + 100

# Colors where each row is (Red, Green, Blue, Alpha).  Each can go
# from 0 to 1.  Alpha is the transparency.
colors = np.random.sample([n, 4])

# Draw all the circles and return an object ``circles`` that allows
# manipulation of the plotted circles.
circles = plt.scatter(pos[:,0], pos[:,1], marker="o", s=sizes, c=colors)

for i in range(100):
    pos = pos + vel
    bounce = abs(pos) > 10     
    vel[bounce] = -vel[bounce]  
    circles.set_offsets(pos)    
    plt.pause(0.05)e
```

I have this code and it plots balls moving in a random manner in the whole plot, I wanted to achieve a plot in which the balls only move in the x axis as like there was a potential that accelerate the balls en the middle of the plot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try modifying your `for` loop as follows:

```
for i in range(100):
    # Compute the additional x-velocity due to the potential
    v_potential = -0.1 * np.sign(pos[:,0])

    # Add the potential to the x-velocity
    vel[:,0] += v_potential

    # Your code
    pos = pos + vel
    bounce = abs(pos) > 10     
    vel[bounce] = -vel[bounce]  
    circles.set_offsets(pos)    
    plt.pause(0.05)
```